# Android - How to open Adobe Acrobat within android application

Tags: android, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I'm developing an android application which is used to display the pdf file. I want to open the adobe acrobat within my android application to open the pdf file.
So please help me how i can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
preet_Android

Comment: install adobe reader and open your pdf file. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hZG9iZS5yZWFkZXIiXQ..

Comment: Thanks, But I've done it. In this case application is go in background and adobe acrobat is open at frontend. But i want to open the pdf file within my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to check whether there is a pdf viewer available in your system.
Therfore you need to call the intent to read a file

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("path-to-document"));
intent.setType("application/pdf");
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
 if (activities.size() > 0) {
   startActivity(intent);
   }  
 else
  {
Toast.maketext("hi there is no pdf viewer in your system");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the pdf file in your app by:

```
File pdfFile = new File("/sdcard/read.pdf"); 
 if(pdfFile.exists()) {
           Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            startActivity(pdfIntent);

   }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I've done it. In this case application is go in background and adobe acrobat is open at frontend. But i want to open the pdf file within my app.

Comment: you can open pdf file in the app by default.if you want to show in activity,than you have to add pdf library in project.

Comment: Thanks @ AkashG. So can you please tell me which pdf library i've to added and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(mRealPath);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try{
       //If pdf reader app already installed it will cause and exception

       startActivity(intent);    

}catch(Exception e)
{
    // IF NO PDF APPLICATION INSTALLED ASK USER TO DOWNLOAD
}
```